# Dynamic table header fixing issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a fully Dynamic table here, all cells are generating Dynamically from the values of database.The problem is How to fix my table header always visible while scrolling x and y axics. Iam just pasting static codes and my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/8gMVJ/5/

```
<div id="container">
<table id="my_table">
<thead>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head1</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>data1</td>
<td>data2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: `#container{ position:fixed; }`?

Comment: The idea is to put the header alone in a separate `table` and put the content in another `table` within a scrollable `div`.Let me see if i can create an example

Comment: make the css for `thead` as `position:fixed`.

Comment: @kannan:See if this fixes your problem:http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/8gMVJ/4/
i Messed up the column alignment

Comment: its not fixed allignment is the main probplem. x axics sroll have problem  check my latest fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/8gMVJ/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some css:

```
#table-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#table-scroll {
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
#table-wrapper table {
  width:100%;

}
#table-wrapper table * {
  background:yellow;
  color:black;
}
#table-wrapper table thead th .text {
  position:absolute;   
  top:-20px;
  z-index:2;
  height:20px;
  width:35%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span class="text">A</span></th>
                <th><span class="text">B</span></th>
                <th><span class="text">C</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<tr> <th>1, 0</th> <th>2, 0</th> <th>3, 0</th> </tr>
<tr> <th>1, 1</th> <th>2, 1</th> <th>3, 1</th> </tr>
<tr> <th>1, 2</th> <th>2, 2</th> <th>3, 2</th> </tr>
<tr> <th>1, 3</th> <th>2, 3</th> <th>3, 3</th> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/Yxekd/)

You can also use

1. [FixedHeaderPlugin](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/)
2. http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html
3. http://imar.spaanjaars.com/357/a-scrollable-table-with-a-fixed-header
4. http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/dBe5w/

Comment: x and y axics scroll is the main problem  please check my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/8gMVJ/5/

Comment: that method looks good. Is that possible with out giving <th> and <td> width. because my table is fully dynamic

Comment: @ Manwal is that possible with single table??

Comment: Ya this is possible but it takes more effort, you can try it also.

Comment: @kannan sorry it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question it seems like you need fixed header / freezing columns click on the below link i hope that helps

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html